# ReflectionException unable to be caught?

Tags: php, exception, reflection

I have this code:

```
namespace Some\Different\Name;
        try {
            $reflect  = new ReflectionClass($class);
X:          $instance = $reflect->newInstanceArgs($args);
        } catch (ReflectionException $e) {
            exit($e->getMessage());
        }
```

and I'm testing it trying to make a ReflectionException be thrown. And it gives me:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message
>   'Class MyClass does not have a constructor, so you cannot pass any
>   constructor arguments' in ... on line X.

What am I doing wrong?

PS: I know why the exception is thrown, I just wanna know why it's not caught!

Comment: Weird indeed. Will a generic `catch (Exception $e)` catch it?

Comment: Please add the backtrace of that error.

Comment: It's really strange, I tested it, just the code below, and it works. In the context I'm working on there I know for sure that `$class` exists, and it is confirmed by the fact that the error say that the class doesn't have a constructor. `$args` is an empty array in this case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally. It was a namespace problem. It's strange by the way that PHP doesn't notify that you are trying to catch an exception of a type (`ReflectionException`) that doesn't exists in the current namespace.

Just adding the `\` to `\ReflectionException` helped me out because now it's able to find what type of exception I'm actually looking for.

Another solution would be to add:

```
use \ReflectionException;
```

just after the namespace declaration.

Comment: There is autoloading, so PHP does not know in advance which exceptions the future will bring ;) And PHP told you that there is an uncaught exception and even named it... it's just easy to oversee when dealing with namespaces. Has happened to the best of us.